# extjs: write an xml without root using xmlwriter

Tags: extjs, extjs4

when sending a response to a server using xmlwriter, the root tag will always be added to the request:

If I want to post an item:

```
<book>
<id></id>
<title></title>
<publisher></publisher>
</book>
```

the actual generated xml is:

```
<xmlData>
<book>
<id></id>
<title></title>
<publisher></publisher>
</book>
</xmlData>
```

I can make sure that only one record will be posted: one book for each request

how can I remove the xmlData element? that is to say, make book tag to be the root element

the extjs document says:

Ext.data.writer.Xml
documentRoot : String

The name of the root element of the document. Defaults to 'xmlData'. If there is **more than 1 record and the root is not specified**, the default document root will still be used to ensure a valid XML document is created.

My understanding is that if **there is only one record**, the default document root will not be used. Am I right? But acturaly, the root element 'xmlData' is still added even if there is only one record.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Ext.data.writer.Xml` class has two configuration properties related to the root element: `documentRoot` and `defaultDocumentRoot`. As you noted, the documentation says:

> If there is more than 1 record and the root is not specified, the default document root will still be used to ensure a valid XML document is created.

In other words, if `documentRoot` is null, but more than one record is written, the value of `defaultDocumentRoot` will be used as the root element. In your case, there is only one record, but `documentRoot` is not null, as its default value is "xmlData".

To omit the root element for single records, then, you need to explicitly set `documentRoot` to null:

```
new Ext.data.writer.Xml({ documentRoot: null });
```